# php ja javascript links and encoding

Tags: javascript, php

With scandinavian letters and when encoding them, I have a problem. With code below, javascript add some extra encoding to variable

```
<script>
    function doit(params) {
       var url = "/linkto/code.php" + params;
       window.open(url,"Doit","width=750, height=600");
    } 
</script>

   <?php
        $values = urlencode($var1); // encoding skandinavian letters
        $param = '?test='.$values;  // add them to variable
        echo '<a href="javascript:doit('.$param.')">Do it!</a>'; // link to page
    ?>
```

When changing code above to php, changed does not happened and problem go away.

```
 $values = urlencode($var1); // encoding skandinavian letters
 $param = '?test='.$values;  // add them to variable
 // link to page
 echo '<a href="/linkto/code.php"'.$param.'>Do it!</a>';
```

Hi all again,

I cannot make it work, no difference between utf-8 or iso-8859-1.
Result is something else, when using javascript-function or direct link.
You can try it here: 
http://www.ajl.fi/tmp/test.php

Here is codes:

test.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doIt(params) {
      var url = "doit.php" + params;
      window.open(url,"doit");
}
</script>
<?php
$var1 = 'pähkinä';
$var1 = urlencode($var1);

echo sprintf("<a href=\"javascript:doIt('?var1=%s');\">Do it - call</a>",$var1)."<br>";
echo sprintf("<a href=\"doit.php?var1=%s\" target=\"_blank\">Do it - link</a>",$var1);
?>
```

and here is doit.php:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

Comment: in above code you have two issues 1) `echo '<a href="javascript:doit('<?=$param?>')">Do it!</a>'; // link to page` **short tag will not work here**, 2) `window.open(url,"Doit",width=750, height=600");` missing quote here

Comment: Maybe something to do with browser? Edge ja Firefox shows it wrong, but IE and chrome ok. ideas?

Comment: maybe friend .. . than u must need to chk firefox

Comment: accepting the correct answer will help to future visitors

Answer (score 0):

In ist code, you have two issues in this code

1) Short tag will not work inside the `<?php ?>` here:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:doit('<?=$param?>')">Do it!</a>'; // link to page
```

2) You forgot to add quotes here:

```
window.open(url,"Doit",width=750, height=600"); //missing quote here
```

**Modified Code:**

```
<?php
$var1 = 'p%E4hkin%E4';
$values = urlencode($var1); // encoding skandinavian letters
$param = '?test='.$values;  // add them to variable
?>
<a href="javascript:doit('<?=$param?>')">Do it!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doit(params) {
   var url = "/linkto/code.php" + params;
   console.log(url);
   window.open(url,"Doit","width=750, height=600");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, my copy/paste mistakes. I corrected them. Thanks!

Comment: `echo $param` and chk and also chk the browser console

Comment: no, it does not :-(   tryed $var1 = 'pähkinä'; and encoding seems to be 
p%E4hkin%E4 sample 2) is working ok and result on code.php is correct p%E4hkin%E4 but when using way 1) result is pÃ¤hkinÃ¤

Comment: @ajlind: chk my modified code, its working fine on my side and giving me a new window

Comment: You should use $var1 = 'pähkinä'; and you need to echo value on /linkto/code.php. Is your webserver utf8? mine is iso-8859-1 - something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself - Solved.

IE, Edge and Chrome, all working ok on both cases. Firefox has a problem. When using

```
<a href="javascript:doit('<?=$param?>')">Do it!</a>
```

result is not correct, but when using

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:doit('<?=$param?>')">Do it!</a>
```

seems to work on all browsers